# Find an estimate for $\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin(x) dx$ using the Monte Carlo Simulation

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, transformation, monte-carlo, simulation

I want to find an estimate for

$$\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \sin(x) dx$$

I want to use the monte carlo simulation method. I've plotted the graph of $\sin(x)$ in the given interval. The total area

$$\begin{align*}
A &= 1\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}\\[5pt]
&=\frac{\pi}{2}\\[5pt]
\end{align*}$$

The target area $a = \big(\frac{n}{N}\big) \cdot A$ where $n$ is the number of hits and $N$ is the total number of 'throws'. I've been given the following random numbers:

$$\begin {align} 
8442 \quad 5653\\ 
2887 \quad 7703\\ 
6412 \quad 3965\\ 
4941 \quad 7376\\ 
0646 \quad 6931\\ 
7556 \quad 9697\\ 
\end {align}$$

What I need to do now is transform my $x$ values so they are in the range $\big(\frac{\pi}{2}, \pi\big)$, the graph only goes up to $y = 1$ so they $y$ values don't need to be transformed. Where I'm struggling is what transformation I should use on the random $x$-values, I tried $x_{transformed} = x_{random} +\big(\frac{\pi}{2}\big)$ but I didn't get any hits, my $\sin(x_{transformed})$ values were very low.

If anyone could help out and show me what transformation I should use on the $x$ values to get them in the range I require it would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

(I'll add the graph of $\sin(x)$ in the interval I require so you can see the rectangle and the target area:)
[image]

Comment: So you are given uniformly distributed random numbers in $[0,10000)$ right? If you divide these numbers by $10000$ in what interval do these numbers now lie? If you then add $1$ to all numbers in what interval do these numbers now lie? You can use this kind of scaling and shifting to get numbers in the desired range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your $x_{random}$ values are from $0$ to $10000$. So dividing by $10000$, $x_{random}/10000$ is in the $[0,1]$ interval. Now multiply by the length of the desired interval, and shift it to the beginning of that interval:
$$\frac{x_{random}}{10000}\frac{\pi}2$$ is in the $[0,\pi/2]$ interval
$$\frac{x_{random}}{10000}\frac{\pi}2+\frac\pi2$$ is in the $[\pi/2,\pi]$ interval

Comment: This makes perfect sense, thanks a lot

Comment: I've used the transformation you provided and calculated all my $sin(x_{transformed})$ values but I don't get a single hit, all my $y$ values are larger than my $sin$ values, I'm not sure why I don't get a single hit. For the $y$ values I just divide them by 10,000 correct? They just have to be in the range (0,1)

Comment: @CharlieP, you _are_ using radians, I hope?

Comment: *checks calculator* Issue found :) I really am my own enemy, thanks Tony